# Excel Export from JAVA of Multi Language Content

Tags: java, excel, multilingual

I'm trying to export and MS Excel sheet from JAVA that involves some Multi-Language (Japanese) content as well. I've tried several things but the Multi-Language (Japanese) content isn't appearing properly in Exported Excel Sheet.

I'm picking up content from Database (I've checked Database,  the Multi-Language-Japanese content is saved properly)

```
String fileName = "output"+".xls";
ExcelExport excelExporter = new ExcelExport();
excelExporter.ExportExcel(fileName, ....);  // Writing Database Fields to Excel
File file = new File(fileName);
int length = 0;
response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
response.setContentLength((int) file.length());
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\""+ file.getName() + "\"");
ServletOutputStream outputStream = response.getOutputStream();
byte[] bbuf = new byte[1024];
DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
while ((in != null) && ((length = in.read(bbuf)) != -1)) 
{
    outputStream.write(bbuf, 0, length);
}

in.close();
outputStream.flush();
outputStream.close();
file.delete();
```

It's showing me encoding **iso-8859-1** (by using  **response.getCharacterEncoding();** function), is that could be the issue ? Because English is going perfectly in Excel file, only Multi-Language (Japanese) is appearing wrong

Comment: You say the Excel data comes from the database - how does it get to the file on your filesystem?

Comment: (Post Updated), Excel data is populated from database by a function excelExporter.ExportExcel();

Comment: What exactly goes wrong? Can you be more specific? (Does the excel file open properly? Do some/all words appear garbled?

Also, what is an `ExcelExporter`? Is it a 3rd party? 
Is the file on the filesystem valid - or also corrupt? (Don't delete it during tests)

Comment: File opens properly, only the Multi-Language-Japanese content appears wrong ... looks like some issue with encoding. ExcelExporter is own written

Comment: Your code seems fine, so I would try something simple - isolate the code that writes to the stream and use it to make a copy of the file - just to see if it creates a perfect copy of the file. (I assume yes - but lets verify)

Also, which format of Excel is it? Excel 2003? 2007? 2010?

Comment: Okay, i'll try that
,Excel 2003

Comment: It's showing me encoding iso-8859-1, is that could be the issue ? Because English is going perfectly in Excel file, only Multi-Language (Japanese) is appearing wrong

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17448/discussion-between-ronk-and-ammar26)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not close the `outputStream` of the response. Furthermore use a BufferedInputStream instead of a DataInputStream which is more for objects.

The test on `in != null` is not necessary. The bbuf dimension might be larger, say 4096.

Comment: Okay, seeing the other comments too I conclude, that the original file you are copying from, is wrong Excel already. If urgent, you could lie, write an UTF-8 encoded html file with ending .xls, and Excel would take that.